# having trouble passing variables between two game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of soil patch game objects which can be turned into flowers. I want to click on flower and open up a new menu. But the soil patches get clicked accidentally when I click on the menu buttons. So I set up a bool so that the soil patches can be turned on and off.

Soil patch code has a bool active. This is what I'm doing in the flower code:

```
 void OnMouseDown()
    {
        public GameObject[] soilpatches= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Soilpatch");
        foreach (GameObject soilpatch in soilpatches)
        {
            SoilPatch _soilpatch=soilpatch.GetComponent<SoilPatch>();
            _soilpatch.active=false;
        }
    }
```

But it keeps giving me compile errors.

EDIT: 'active' is a bool I've set up inside the soilpatch script.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was declaring a public variable inside onMouseDown()

Answer (score -1):

change the last line to:
_soilpatch.SetActive(false);

Comment: active is a boolean I setup inside soilpatch.